# How to prove A is a subset of B

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble proving this one. Anybody want to take a shot at it?

Prove

> $A \subseteq B \iff B^c \subseteq A^c$

Comment: it will be helpful to provide an attempt.

Comment: Hint: *contrapositive*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A \subseteq B \iff B^c \subseteq A^c$ means $ A \cap B = A$

$(A \cap B)^c = A^c$

$A^c \cup B^c = A^c$

$B^c \subseteq A^c$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $A \subseteq B$. For $x \in B^c$, $x \not\in B$, so $x \not\in A$ since $A$ is included in $B$. Therefore $x \in A^c$.

For the other direction, replace $A$ with $B^c$ and $B$ with $A^c$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in A \implies x \in B$.

Assume $x \in B^c$. Thus, $x \not \in B \implies (x \not \in A \iff x \in A^c)$. You can see this by contradiction.

Now, for the other implication let $x \in B^c \implies x \in A^c.$

Assume $x \in A$. Thus, $x  \not \in A^c \implies (x \not \in B^c \iff x \in B).$

Therefore, $A \subseteq B \iff B^c \subseteq A^c$.